# How to make a function that changes the default language

Tags: javascript

html

```
<form id="langList">
<select class="langOptions dropdown py-0" id="langSelect">
option class="lang" value="Language">Language</option>
option class="lang" value="es" selected>Spanish</option>
 <option class="lang" value="fr">French</option>
 <option class="lang" value="it">Italian</option>
</select>
 </form>
```

JS

```
cardsToTranslate.forEach((cardToTranslate) => {
 const x = document.getElementById('langSelect');
 x.addEventListener('change', event => {
langTo = event.target.value;
```

At the moment the above code allows me choose the language i want from the list. However, i would like to make spanish as a default language and only be able to choose between italian and french languages. Will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const changeLang = (e) => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  console.log(value)
}
```

```html
<form id="langList">
<select class="langOptions dropdown py-0" id="langSelect" onchange="changeLang(event)">
<option class="lang" value="" disabled>Select language</option>
<option class="lang" value="es" selected="true" disabled>Spanish</option>
 <option class="lang" value="fr">French</option>
 <option class="lang" value="it">Italian</option>
</select>
</form>
```

You are missing the disabled attribute, to not allow users to select Spanish option, I have added the same attribute for the select language too.

Comment: Thanks Nicolae. It does work, but not 100 what i need, probably didnt explain correctly. i am building memory game.
 langTo in my code passes the user choice of language to API Google translate. If apply your code id does not pass 'es' to API. User choice pass the language either es or it or fr to langTo.